# React Navigation v6 Best Structure

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am working on react-navigation v6 and was wondering if the below two structures makes difference in terms of performance, especially since I am doing deeplinking to the details screen.

First Structure:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();  

function HomeTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={AccountScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Orders" component={OrderScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabs} />
        <Stack.Screen name="FeedDetails" component={FeedDetails} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ProfileDetails" component={ProfileDetails} />
        <Stack.Screen name="AccountDetails" component={AccountDetails} />
        <Stack.Screen name="OrderDetails" component={OrderDetails} />  
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Second Structure:

```
const FeedStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const ProfileStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const AccountStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const OrderStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function FeedStackScreen() {
  return (
    <FeedStack.Navigator>
      <FeedStack.Screen name="FeedScreen" component={FeedScreen} />
      <FeedStack.Screen name="FeedDetails" component={FeedDetails} />
    </FeedStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function ProfileStackScreen() {
  return (
    <ProfileStack.Navigator>
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen} />
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="ProfileDetails" component={ProfileDetails} />
    </ProfileStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function AccountStackScreen() {
  return (
    <AccountStack.Navigator>
      <AccountStack.Screen name="AccountScreen" component={AccountScreen} />
      <AccountStack.Screen name="AccountDetails" component={AccountDetails} />
    </AccountStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function OrderStackScreen() {
  return (
    <OrderStack.Navigator>
      <OrderStack.Screen name="OrderScreen" component={OrderScreen} />
      <OrderStack.Screen name="OrderDetails" component={OrderDetails} />
    </OrderStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={AccountStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Order" component={OrderStackScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: i think 2nd is better. it is also in official documentation.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib the first one is also in their documentation

Comment: i personally preferred 2nd because it is more easy and understandable with clean code. and you will have proper hierarchy.

Comment: thanks for ur input @NajamUsSaqib, I was using the 2nd structure in react-navigation v4 and had some issues with the performance(memory leak) in Android cause of the nested stack, that was the motive of this question. personally, I like the first one, since less code and direct deeplinking but not sure if it would affect the performance.

Comment: I also prefer the second structure, It is clean and readable. I Also recommend you to utilize typescript in you projects because it gives you more power when you are doing deep nesting and going to pass some route parameters. You can have really helpful static typing of the parameters and route names

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of the structures you posted are fine based on your requirements. They produce 2 different types of UIs so what's better entirely depends on what kind of UI you want.

In the first one (stack at root, tabs in the first screen), when you navigate to other screens, the tab bar is not visible on those screens. So if this is the UI you want, go with the first one.

In the second one, (tab at root, stacks nested inside each tab), when you navigate to other screens, the tab bar is still present. So if you want this behavior, go with the second one.